# Python is not working in unbuffered mode

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, buffering, unbuffered

I'm stuggeling with an issue with python. I used Python 2.7.13 and Python 3.6.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo). In order to monitor the proccesses output, I want to use `tail -f` to take a live look into the STDOUT and STDERR. The Keyword here is unbuffered output. Many suggestion on the internet say use `python -u ...` or the environment variable PYTHONUNBUFFERED like `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python ...` or `stdbuf -e0 -o0 python ...`. Nevertheless nothing is wokring for the following test script.

```
import sys
import time
while(True):
   print("Test String")
   time.sleep(1);
```

For all different commands I always have buffered output. Even though when I want to use STDERR. It's still buffered which really confuses me because STDERR should be unbuffered by default. Using `sys.stdout.flush()` or `sys.stderr.flush()` is also not doing the job. When using `flush=True` inside `print()` it's working as intended.

I'm looking for a solution which doesn't make it necessary to edit code because I can't edit all programs in order to get unbuffered and immediately flushed out output. How can I achieve this?

Looking forward to your answers!

Best wishes!

Comment: What do you expect your test script does?

Comment: You can override `print(flush=True)` function.

Comment: So my original script has some output of deep learning and neural network steps I want to monitor. In my test script I narrowed it down to some dummy output to see if the output is unbuffered. @ElisByberi for that I've got to edit code. Some programs are so huge it would end in a mess to edit it all.. I'm looking for something `python -u` or `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` instead that they're working.. I don't even know why they're not working as advertised.

Comment: Again. What do you want `print("Test String")` to do that it doesn't? no matter if buffered or not, the output will be the same.

Comment: As described in my original post, I want to call a python script in the background which is creating stdout and stderr output in files. From time to time I want to monitor output created by this script via `print` with `tail` to see how the progress is. `print("Test String")` is just a dummy script with which I want to test that. Until now, stdout and stderr as well as `print` create buffered output when redirecting them into a file. Therefore it is hard to monitor my logs with `tailf` because I get new output every 4-6 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override `print()` function in Python 3. This way you will not need to change every `print()` function in your scripts.

```
import builtins


def print(*args):
    builtins.print(*args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None, flush=True)


print(
    'hello', 'world',
    'I have overrode print() function!',
    1,  # integer
    [1, 2],  # list
    {1, 2},  # set
    (1, 2),  # tuple
    {1: 2}  # dict
)
```

will print:

```
hello world I have overrode print() function! 1 [1, 2] {1, 2} (1, 2) {1: 2}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately the output is `('Test String',)`. I'd be happiest when `python -u`or `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` would work as advertised.. do you know if I missed something regarding those to options?

Comment: @TheOrangeman To be honest, I did not test the code. I put it there as an example only. It works now as expected. Thank you for reporting it.

Comment: @TheOrangeman Try this command: `python -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0 yourscript.py`

Comment: Hey Elis, thanks for correction. As you said, the builtins function works now as advertised by you. When trying `python -e` both of my python Installations say that the `-e` parameter is an unknown option :(

Comment: @TheOrangeman In `python --help` are listed all options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables). It is capital E. This would work: `python -E PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0 yourscript.py`

Comment: Also not working. The Documentation tells me about this `-E Ignore all PYTHON* environment variables, e.g. PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME, that might be set.` Weirdly enough `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python [...]` is working now... I triple checked the spelling of the environment variable. I can't explain this and feel really dumb that I took your time. Thanks for your efforts @Elias Byberi.

Comment: @ElisByberi does this function override even prints inside packages?

Comment: @LeonardoRick You can override a function in a script only, then you can import that script in other scripts. E.g. You override function `print()` in script custom.py and wherever you import custom.py function `print()` will get overridden.

Comment: @ElisByberi The problem is when the print is maded inside a dependecy library of my project. This way I can't override this method print so your solution do not work for me

Comment: @LeonardoRick It’s not perfectly clear to me what it is you’re trying to say.

Comment: @ElisByberi I use a library (pyrogram) that emits a print itself. This print will not be unbeffered if I just override the function on my `main.py`

Comment: @LeonardoRick I emphasize that **"You can override a function in a script only."** E.g. If you override function `print()` in script main.py, it will not override that function anywhere else.